# Why the browser opened by IdentityModel OidcClient Browser InvokeAsync does not use all the screen available in iPad (iOS) [MAUI]

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, openid-connect, maui

Why the browser opened by IdentityModel OidcClient Browser InvokeAsync does not use all the screen available in iPad (iOS)

We are developing this in MAUI with latest versions of visual studio 2022

[How it looks in iPad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3t6Nz.png)

As you can see, in android tablet the browser uses all space available.

[How it looks in Android Tablet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEi3O.jpg)

Even in iPhone the browser uses all space available

[How it looks in iPhone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wobd7.png)

The code we are using to make the authentication is the following.

We would want that the behavior in IPad was similar to the one in iPhone.

Any idea?

```
public async Task<LoginSession> LoginAsync()
    {
        List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> parameters = new()
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>(OidcConstants.AuthorizeRequest.ResponseType, OidcConstants.ResponseTypes.IdTokenToken),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>(OidcConstants.AuthorizeRequest.Nonce, Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"))
        };
    
        AuthorizeState state = await oidcClient.PrepareLoginAsync(new Parameters(parameters));
    
        state.StartUrl = state.StartUrl.Replace("response_type=code&", "");
    
        var request = new LoginRequest();
    
        var browserOptions = new BrowserOptions(state.StartUrl, options.RedirectUri)
        {
            Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(request.BrowserTimeout),
            DisplayMode = request.BrowserDisplayMode
        };
    
        var browserResult = await options.Browser.InvokeAsync(browserOptions);
    
        string browserResponse = string.Empty;
        string Error = string.Empty;
        string ErrorDescription = string.Empty;
    
        if (browserResult.ResultType == BrowserResultType.Success)
            browserResponse = browserResult.Response;
        else
        {
            Error = browserResult.Error ?? browserResult.ResultType.ToString();
            ErrorDescription = browserResult.ErrorDescription;
        }
    
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(browserResponse))
        {
            var url = new Uri(browserResponse);
    
            string queryString = url.Query;
            var queryParse = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString);
            var queryDictionary = queryParse.ToDictionary();
            var loginSession = queryDictionary.ToObject<LoginSession>();
            //loginSession.oidcClient = oidcClient;
            //loginSession.options = options;
    
            return loginSession;
        }
    
        return new LoginSession
        {
            Error = Error,
            ErrorDescription = ErrorDescription
        };
    }
```

We have looked upon the options avaialable in Browser option, but no one seams to help:

```
// Copyright (c) Brock Allen & Dominick Baier. All rights reserved.
// Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0. See LICENSE in the project root for license information.

using System;

namespace IdentityModel.OidcClient.Browser
{
/// \<summary\>
/// Options for the browser used for login.
/// \</summary\>
public class BrowserOptions
{
/// \<summary\>
/// Gets the start URL.
/// \</summary\>
/// \<value\>
/// The start URL.
/// \</value\>
public string StartUrl { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the end URL.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The end URL.
        /// </value>
        public string EndUrl { get; }
    
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the browser display mode.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The display mode.
        /// </value>
        public DisplayMode DisplayMode { get; set; } = DisplayMode.Visible;
    
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the browser timeout.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The timeout.
        /// </value>
        public TimeSpan Timeout { get; set; } = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
    
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="BrowserOptions"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="startUrl">The start URL.</param>
        /// <param name="endUrl">The end URL.</param>
        public BrowserOptions(string startUrl, string endUrl)
        {
            StartUrl = startUrl;
            EndUrl = endUrl;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Those are the integrated system browsers, called `Chrome Custom Tab` on Android, or `ASWebAuthenticationSessionWindow` in iOS. Using them keeps user credentials external to the app. It is a best practice according to [RFC8252](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8252). You won't be able to change the appearance though - and neither can other apps that use this type of login, eg gmail.